# How to get the message being passed in torch geometric?

Tags: pytorch, normalization, pytorch-geometric, gnn

I am working on a project with GNN with Torch Geometric. I wanted to try the layer norm.MessageNorm, however it requires in the forward step as inputs the following (as of [documentation](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/torch_geometric.nn.norm.MessageNorm.html)):

- x (torch.Tensor) – The source tensor.
- msg (torch.Tensor) – The message tensor
- p (float, optional) – The norm to use for normalization. (default: 2.0)

**x** will be as usual the output of the previous layer, however, **where do I get the msg needed?**

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The `msg` is a parameter that you input into the `forward` method of the `MessageNorm` class, so if you don't have any messages aggregated that you want to normalize then this doesn't apply. Or just input `msg=torch.ones(x.shape).float()`.